# Minimax MILP problem

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, minimax

I have a MILP model which defines a relation between three real variables $x$, $y$ and $s$ where $s = f(x,y)$.

I want to optimize the following objective: $$\min_x\max_y s$$

How can I achieve it?

EDIT:
The problem is MILP because the relation $f$ stacks linear operations between $x$ and $y$ with non-linear operations that rely on binary variables.
To be more specific, $f$ is a simple deep neural network with ReLU activations encoded with indicator contraints.

Comment: You said "MILP" (so presumably $f()$ is linear), but specified that $x,y,s$ are all real-valued. Are there other (integer) variables? Can you give us a reasonably compact representation of the full problem?

Comment: @prubin I edited the  question, ty

Comment: [Input Convex Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.07152)?

Comment: Still not enough information on this. You don't have any constraints?

Comment: @Brannon i do have several indicator constraints used to encode the neural network $f()$